# Paths.get("/xyz") returns \xyz instead of /xyz

Tags: java, path, filesystems, nio

I am trying to create a virtual file system using Apache MINA virtual file system. While creating new file system for a specific user using own customized provider, i need to set the root of the file system which will act as a key to get the file system in further processes. 
So in order to set the root directory i do `Paths.get("schema://" +userName)`. which is not working as expected as i explained below.

Seeking a value of `/xyz` from `Paths.get("/xyz")` but it returns `'\xyz'`. The above requirement is to save the File System with the key as path value. When i try to save the file system using Paths.get() as key mentioned above it saves with a `\` instead of `/` and becomes difficult while retrieving it with actual value. Below are the versions which i have tried

```
Paths.get("/xyz")
Paths.get(File.pathSeparator+ "xyz")
Paths.get(File.separator+"xyz")
```

they return

```
\xyz
;xyz
\xyz
```

Any way if i could achieve this?

Comment: You've already asked [the exact same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60258786/paths-get-xyz-returns-xyz-but-i-want-it-to-return-xyz). It was closed because unclear and it is still unclear...

Comment: If the `/` is being converted to a ``\`` then most likely the default `FileSystem` (the one delegated to by `Paths#get(String,String...)`) uses ``\`` as the separator. Are you by any chance on Windows when testing your code?

Comment: Yes that is true. I did set my custom provider and its getting called also, but now how am i suppose to convert any path which will give me relative path as per my schema instead of giving windows one. The code is working fine on Mac

Comment: Path.of or Paths.get is specified to use the default provider. Maybe you are looking for the FileSystem getPath method?

Comment: Are you sure NIO is the correct API for what you're trying to do? Do you have some other `FileSystemProvider` / `FileSystem` implementation that you should be using, rather than the default?

Comment: I have overridden the file system in my own way, so that whenever i try to create or get path it should return my custom class path which has overridden BasePath class. For this scenario i cant use that class since i am creating the file system and till then my custom path class is not called yet.

Comment: If you are creating a custom file system then it needs to exist before you can create paths that locate files in it.

Comment: Correct. But if i need to fix a root for that file system, i need to set that as a path for that particular file system and this is where i am facing this issue.

Comment: Sounds like you might be looking for the environment/properties that are used to configure a file system when creating it. That's the place to set the initial root.

Comment: @AlanBateman Yes, thats what i am trying to do, it should take my file system root instead of windows or any other installed provider.

Comment: Unless you set the custom path, if you call `Paths.get()` it returns the windows path. So i did a work around in setting the root of the file system as common as `/` instead of specific to user. So this issue is solved now. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Path.of (and Paths.get) creates a Path that locates a file in the default file system. So if you are on Windows then it will of course give you a Windows path. The FileSystems javadoc describes how you can interpose on the default file system provider, which is what is what you are trying to do

Comment: Correct. So what i wanted to achieve couldn't be achieved before i set the custom file system. That is why i changed my approach to setting the file system common and then setting path based on user specific. It works now.